# How to add a div below image Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a div below an image that is responsive to the image as it shrinks or is enlarged. I've tried adding div's underneath the image, but it doesn't respond to the image scaling. How would I accomplish something like this:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```css
#books_div {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#books_text {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 15%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#books_div img {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Books -->
    <h2 id='books_text'> We Giveaway Free Books </h2>
    <div class="row" id='books_div'>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1474154022l/3.jpg" alt=""  style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1328767473l/10713286.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1394566113l/20454074.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1460309528l/44652.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- End of Books -->
```

Comment: Hi @user6902601, as far as I get your idea. I think you can try the next approach: Setting the image and description´s test in a div at the same level, and set an upper div as a parent. Then you can set the width of the image and the description (for example: 80, 100 respectively) against the upper parent.

Comment: @GileadKenzo I'm a bit confused. Can you show me an example? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want it like this? I just added a new `div` called `description`, removed the `margin-bottom: 20px !important` and gave it `description`.

Remember that when your parent div have a width like `width of parent > image width`, the div will have the parent `width`.

**Update:**

I've added `max-width: 200px` to `.description`.

```css
#books_div {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#books_text {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 15%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

/*
#books_div img {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}
*/

.description {
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Books -->
    <h2 id='books_text'> We Giveaway Free Books </h2>
    <div class="row" id='books_div'>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1474154022l/3.jpg" alt=""  style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                </a>
                <div class="description">test</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1328767473l/10713286.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                </a>
                <div class="description">test</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1394566113l/20454074.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                </a>
                <div class="description">test</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1460309528l/44652.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                </a>
                <div class="description">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- End of Books -->
```

Comment: Thank you, but there is one part of the window where the div doesn't match with the image. I have provided an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWRbl.png) to show... :)

Comment: @user6902601 I've updated my answer. Now it should work like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below.
Simply write a div inside a tag.

```css
#books_div {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

#books_text {
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 15%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}


#name {
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Books -->
    <h2 id='books_text'> We Giveaway Free Books </h2>
    <div class="row" id='books_div'>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1474154022l/3.jpg" alt=""  style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                    <div class="name">Book Name</div>
                </a>
            
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1328767473l/10713286.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                    <div class="name">Book Name</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1394566113l/20454074.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                    <div class="name">Book Name</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1460309528l/44652.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:276px;">
                     <div class="name">Book Name</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- End of Books -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be an acceptable approach, if I get your needed:

You should set a container (div) as a parent, it will define the absolute width. Then, it will have two children (image and description), whose you can set with your required needded:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
    <div style="width:100%;"><a href="#">
        <img class='img-responsive' src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1474154022l/3.jpg" alt=""  style="width:200px;height:276px;">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; background-color:red;" class="description">test</div>
</div>
```

Realize, I´m setting the css styles in the own html tag, you could create or set them in a Css class.

Hoping it helps. If you have any question, please let me know.